How to change font properties of Excel data output in Outlook meeting request
This script works.
I want a particular range to be in bold and to change font color.
Sub SendMeeting()
    
    Dim objOL   'As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAppt 'As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim rw As Long

    Const olAppointmentItem = 1
    Const olMeeting = 1
        
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objAppt = objOL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    With objAppt
        .Subject = Sheet1.Range("F" & 2)
        .Start = Sheet1.Range("C" & 2)
        .End = Sheet1.Range("D" & 2)
        ' make it a meeting request
        .Location = Sheet1.Range("E" & 2)
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .RequiredAttendees = Sheet1.Range("B" & 2)
        .body = Sheet1.Range("J" & 2) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          Sheet1.Range("B" & 25) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          Sheet1.Range("H" & 2) & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine
                        
        .Attachments.Add Range("I2").Value
        .Categories = "Green Category"
        .display
        .reminderset = True
        .reminderminutesbeforestart = (Sheet1.Range("G" & 2) * 15)
    End With
            
    Set objAppt = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub

I want the output of
Sheet1.Range("B" & 25) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

in bold and red color in the Outlook meeting request.

Your code is setting the plain text AppointmentItem.Body property. For regular messages, you'd need to set HTMLBody property, but AppointmentItem object does not expose it. It does expose RTFBody property, which is a byte array, not a string. You can hardcode it and insert your data into a template, but it won't be pretty.

What can be  done to fix the code.
Kindly help me sorting the code.

As I suggested above, you need to set the RTFBody property instead.
